# Euclid's algorithm for polynomials on MAGMA

Tags: polynomials, math-software, euclidean-algorithm

I have to compute the GCD between two polynomials on MAGMA. I do not have any problem with the Euclidean Algorithm but I have a problem with the function "mod" that, as they say on the MAGMA Handbook, given two polynomials f and g should give the remainder of the division between f and g. It doesn't work.

For example, using f(x)=x^2 and g(x)=x it returns
"Runtime error in 'mod': Bad argument types
Argument types given: RngMPolElt, RngMPolElt".

Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: @AnotherUser why is this off-topic? "Mathematics Stack Exchange is for people studying mathematics at any level and professionals in related fields. We welcome questions about....Software that mathematicians use (except Mathematica, which has its own Stack Exchange site)."

Comment: @DavidSheard My mistake. I will delete my comment then.

Comment: The 'magma' tag is certainly off-topic. Possibly a confusion between the software and the algebraic structure?

Comment: I've replaced the tag "magma" with "math-software".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me. Try pasting the following code into the [online Magma calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) and pressing "submit".

```
P<x> := PolynomialRing(Rationals());
f:=x^2;
g:=x;
print f mod g;
```

Note the first line of the code.   Before you can do anything with polynomials in an indeterminate $\ x\ $ in Magma, you have to tell it that "$x$" is a symbol representing the indeterminate of some polynomial ring, which is what the command in the first line of the above code does.

Comment: Thank you , I wrote P<x> := PolynomialRing(Rationals(),1); and it didn't work but using your code it is correct.